W25N01G with littlefs
I'm trying to implement the littefs system with a w25n01g chip and an stm32f405with SPI. Regarding the w25n01 library I use this one here
Here is what I've tried :
struct lfs_config cfg_lfs_w25n = { //My lfs config
    .read = lfs_read,
    .prog = lfs_prog,
    .erase = lfs_erase,
    .sync = lfs_sync,
    .read_size = 2048,
    .prog_size = 2048,
    .block_size = 64*2048,
    .block_count = 1024,
    .cache_size = 4*2048,
    .lookahead_size = 64,
    .block_cycles = 500,
};

All my lfsfunctions calling library function :

int lfs_sync(const struct lfs_config *c) {
  return 0;
}

int lfs_erase(const struct lfs_config *c, lfs_block_t block) {
  LOG_DEBUG("block %lu %d", block, c->block_size);
  W25NXX_Erase_Block128K(block * c->block_size);
  return 0;
}

int lfs_prog(const struct lfs_config *c, lfs_block_t block, lfs_off_t offset, const void *buffer, lfs_size_t size) {
  W25NXX_Write((uint8_t *)buffer , (block * c->block_size + offset), size);
  return 0;
}

int lfs_read(const struct lfs_config *c, lfs_block_t block, lfs_off_t offset, void *buffer, lfs_size_t size) {
  W25NXX_Read((uint8_t *)buffer , (block * c->block_size + offset), size);
  return 0;
}

And for testing :
int f = lfs_format(&lfs, &cfg_lfs_w25n);
LOG_DEBUG("code format = %d", f);
int err = lfs_mount(&lfs, &cfg_lfs_w25n);
LOG_DEBUG("code mount = %d", err);

I encounter a problem when formatting my chip, I got LFS_ERR_NOSPC error code, but mount works well and return 0. Don't understand what I've missed configuration and/or erase function ?

LFS_ERR_NOSPC means no space? Sounds like a pretty special error message when formatting. There can't be many places in the code that can return this code. Can you track it down?
